# Windows OS displaying unknown character vertical rectangles in browsers

Tags: html, css, mysql, wordpress

I had an interesting issue pop up today on a couple of websites I host. Specifically a vertical rectangle character is displaying (mostly) near 
 characters in my code (though I tend to use those sparingly) but only on Windows machines. I've only seen one instance where that the vertical character has displayed in the middle of a paragraph.

I checked the site in Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac and didn't see any issues. Even more interestingly, when I log in to the site backend on the Windows machine, the vertical rectangle character is actually selectable and deletable. No clue why this is happening.

Both sites are running on Wordpress. I've attached a screenshot for reference. Thanks!

[Unknown Character Reference Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LBm3.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) If you, having the code, don't have a clue imagine how hard is to find any reason for this issue without having access to any code... Please, read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a character that your font doesn't know how to render properly. Try to copy and paste it into google, and see what it says it is. Chances are it is safe to remove it, try retyping that bit of information WITHOUT copying and pasting. Else, try a different font and see if it is still there. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) for more; specifically: *The replacement character � (often a black diamond with a white question mark or an **empty square box**) is a symbol found in the Unicode standard at codepoint U+FFFD in the Specials table.* (Bold Added)

Comment: Thanks HeroCC - I think I figured it out. It was happening only on content that had been copy and pasted from my Photoshop site mock-up. The character was showing up where a line break in the text would occur. For any devs that work from a Photoshop/Creative Suite mock-up, make sure you clean your text in text edit or something similar prior to pasting in your site code!